# Closing popup window without javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on an existing vbulletin site and new to vbulletin. The login for the forums uses a popup window. The window is opened thru a link

```
 <li><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a></li>
```

Once the window opens, it has the login information and a close (x) button. But clicking the button does nothing 90% of the time. The other 10% it closes the window, and that's usually after cache has been cleared and parent window closed and reopened. But even that doesn't always work. Here is the code for closing the window:

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
<a href="#" class="close">
  <img rc="{vb:stylevarmgdir_misc}/close_popup.png" class="close-button" 
  title="Close" alt="Close" /></a>
```

Everything I can find on this issue uses javascript to close but since it's not opened using js, when i try the window.close() it closes the parent window. Is there anyway to close this without javascript, or am i going to have to change the open window part to js and use that?

Comment: Is not using a popup window for login an option? You should ideally just use a form embedded on the page.

Comment: I think you can use `window.close()`, but only if you saved the reference in a variable `var myWindow = window.open(...)`, there might be other ways but I don't know them

Comment: I doubt this is a “real” popup window – but rather a page overlay of some sort …